# What Is The Best Way To Constantly Check And Process Items In A Queue?

Tags: vb.net, queue, threadpool

I have part of my application that receives string messages from remote clients and decodes these into a `_Message` class.  I then want to pass these messages into a queue for immediate processing.  The FIFO method is exactly what I require as I would particularly prefer to process these messages in order of receiving.

These messages come in fairly constant (24 hours a day, maybe 1 every couple of seconds or so...) so I need to ensure that I capture them all and no messages get lost or rejected.

Each `_Message` will then run through a Routine which will decode and action various parts of the message content.

Therefore, what would be the best way of handling a constant message pool?  I started to go down the path of Queues with `Queue.Enqueue` and `Queue.Dequeue` but I'm not sure how to constantly poll for items within the Queue without affecting performance or resources.

I then came across ThreadPooling (something very new to me) which sounds like it could be down the right path, but I'm not 100% sure on how it works or how to set it up correctly.

Or....can I use ThreadPooling in conjunction with a Queue?  And simply add items into my Queue and have the ThreadPool automatically detect new items?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I think this question is the same and the answer also applies to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3645105/578843 . I would recommend to use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472.aspx) (or you could [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/NServiceBus) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or any other message queuing system).

Comment: You should definitely use the Queue collection and you either want threading, which can be a little difficult for a noob, or you can use a timer. I would suggest a timer.

Comment: @Steve Could you please elaborate why a Queue would be more beneficial than MSMQ?  Also, could you maybe specify how I should go about setting it up?  Even if it is dot points.  Thankyou

Comment: The advantage of MSMQ is that your own service doesn't have to be running for the other software to send messages. This is very handy if you for example have to do some maintenance or have to install a new version. The other application can keep doing its work while you do any task on your own service.

Comment: The reason I think you should use a Queue Collection over MSMQ is that 1: It sounds like you have done most of the work to get your messages already so this should take the least effort to integrate where MSMQ will make you revamp the core of you applications. 2: If your asking a question of this level on here, implementing MSMQ might be at a higher difficulty that your comfortable with. No offense, just inferring your level of comfort.

Comment: @Steve No offense taken and I do understand where you're coming from.  Thankyou.  I decided to use ThreadPooling rather than a Queue, I'm hoping that will give me the same results.